# passing multiple parameters through html.actionlink asp.net-mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

i am new to net-mvc.i have a page that has a checkInDate at the begining and list of rooms that i pulled out from the database and listed on the page using foreach loop. i have a button on each list which when selected should pass the id of the room and checkinDate.  i am trying to pass checkInDate input along with the id of the selected room through an anchor tag in the button. How do i go about doing that.
[here is the view of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI07R.png)

```
@model thePortfolio.Models.CustomerNRoomViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index Booking";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="box">

    <h4>Room</h4>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="box">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Book.CheckInDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Book.CheckInDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        foreach (var item in Model.RoomList)
        {
            var image = @item.RoomType.ToString() + ".jpg";
            image = image.Replace(" ", String.Empty);

            <div class="row box">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="~/img/rooms/@image">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">

                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.RoomId)<br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.RoomType)<br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description)

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <h4>Rates from</h4>
                    <i>per night</i>
                    <h2 style="color:red">$@item.Price</h2>

                    @if (item.BookingStatus)
                    {
                        <button type="button" disabled>Not Available</button>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <button>@Html.ActionLink("Book This", "bookRoom", new { id = item.RoomId })</button>


                    }
                </div>
            </div>
                <p></p>


        }

    }
</div>
```

Comment: `CheckInDate` is editable in the view, so you would need to use javascript to update the `href` attribute based on the actual value of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Well...
I think that in your controller, you need to add a method with an id parameter. Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, CustomerNRoomViewModel model)
```

The id parameter should be sent as a value in the query string of the http call.

Comment: OP is asking how to pass the value in a link (i.e. to a GET method, not a POST method)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Sorry, maybe my english is failing me (I'm not a native speaker), but that's not what I understood. If you are right, then your suggestion to use JavaScript browser-side to retrieve the CheckInDate is correct. He should also remove the Html.BeginForm helper (there is no need for a html form anymore)